# Trying to use sudo with bash subshell: env variables not working

Tags: shell, sudo

I have read a few other posts, it appears cumbersome to do multiple commands within sudo. Heredocs suffer from limitation of not being able to do redirection of stdin/stdout. Here in any case is a portion of logic I want to run, edited to contain a particular issue:  the DIR env var does not 'live' past its instantiation in the first commmand?  What is the correct way to have persistent env vars within the subshell?

```
  $ sudo -- /bin/bash -c "(export DIR=/etc/sources.list.d; echo dir is $DIR; mkdir -p $DIR; touch $DIR/cloudera.list)"

dir is
mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't with `sudo`, but your quoting. Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

If you want a variable to be interpreted by a subshell in any context (`sudo`, `ssh`, etc.), you need to escape its special meaning so that its parsing doesn't occur within the current shell.

This is effectively being sent to sudo:

`/bin/bash -c (export DIR=/etc/sources.list.d; echo dir is ; mkdir -p ; touch /cloudera.list)`